# PhalconPHP: "Partial objects" and relationship calls?

Tags: php, orm, phalcon

So, I'm setting up relationships with PhalconPHP and then trying to access those relationships from an object.

When I do:

```
Companies::find()[0]->companyTitles
```

it works fine.    But when I add fields to it, it doesn't:

```
Companies::find(array('fields'=>'id,name'))[0]->companyTitles
// Gives: Undefined property: Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row::$companyTitles
```

I know I'm getting back a partial object when I specify fields, but does that mean that I'm unable to use some of the "more advanced" features?  (I *am* asking for the id).  I'd just rather not have to pull back everything from the database if I don't need everything (performance and all...).

Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really fail to understand you here. First you limit the dataset retrieved from DB to just two fields - `id` and `name`, then you're trying to access the third field - `companyTitles`. How on Earth you expect your model to get you this property?

Comment: companyTitles isn't a third field....  it's a relationship, as defined in the initialize function via 

    $this->hasMany('id', 'CompanyTitles', 'company_id');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, the type of the returned object is `\Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Row`. When you limit the fields, the type of the returned object is not your model, and that means you don't have access to all the extra functionality on your model, and you can only use the properties to have access to the values you have previously noted.

TL;DR: No, you can't, because what you get is not an instance of `Companies`.